# Media source api, stream simple mp4

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4, mpeg-dash, media-source

Can we stream simple mp4 using the media source api?

As we can stream the dash/fmp4 using the media source api but I have the simple mp4 h264 video which I want to stream using the media source api.

I know the mp4 can be directly streamed using html tag etc but I am building the adaptive bitrate streaming of simple mp4 h264 files so that is why I want to use the media source api.

Media source api requires the initial segment for dash/fmp4, if the simple mp4 is supported then which initial segment I have to provide? Means the mov atom, mdat etc

As for the next segments I have extracted the i-frame data from the mp4 file, did media source api accepts raw i-frame data without any container?

Comment: see this example - http://tutorialspots.com/example-using-mediasource-to-play-mp4-file-by-range-4198.html - but, why are you trying to recreate the wheel? If you are doing adaptive bitrate streaming then HLS or MPEG-DASH support (native to browsers or via players like Shaka or Mux) give that to you

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can't do because I have the thousands of video and each video have 3 qualities which are 480p, 720p and 1080p. Each quality have the different keyframe position so they can't be adaptive streamed so I have to develop the custom player so it can be adaptive streamed even if the videos have the different keyframe position.

Comment: The example which you send is for the fragment mp4. My mp4 videos are simple.

Comment: IMO you'd be better off throwing some compute at it now and transcoding the 1080 assets to HLS or Dash and not trying to create a non-standard player which is going to leave you with long term technical debt. ffmpeg can be scripted to churn through the videos locally (and/or you could spin up cloud instances with any provider to get through the work faster)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will transmux the videos to Hls